warp json reply with formatted string for private key
I am using warp reply json format in my web application to create a public/private key pair for an oAuth flow. Private key is returned as json in an warp endpoint to user in an api as below,
Actual Output
{
    "token_uri": "http://example.com/token",
    "kid": "keyid",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\nq0oUrqcHheFb4aCv1N5io6ok\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
}

where private key is with line break(\n) in JSON. Is it possible to format the private key in json as below?
Expected output
{
    "token_uri": "http://example.com/token",
    "kid": "keyid",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQC/Z0MgEolvLiwM
NWpRR+xN6+sXNZh9HU7ignGMgieHz147D/ti7kD1cb14F9Sfp2CewfjwapdMjkhF
/7sytl54ylNV5ID9EIBDlbbJ78IdEu4CzvbdhBP32k5IEQCACI4wMQmqLRj01Wbg
l0ihNPkNFkuVxfmSC5ozJuiVXsR/rCg7GP9w880tkJI50ZoUNwClaLOXWph151Es
jc0HDgrYaDISzLB8qLxEBQCTBLz9OWz38rV0bfLGnBRYZjFx4gzkuZbjJfE2w3XQ
uAl08A0THdNztffoWQLED98jxBj3Y5PRsiC9oqccKb51crohYe426GnfiaAGiPQy
jGI+2ZBRAgMBAAECggEAS+VjbZ1MF+UEHFc18EMHxaIt10cuTzZG6HR3GBMoH6cv
o1XkBceZxHm0eqFgc2pIWstprdNmaTnmGLOeBC7iaR05TE7Ogwp/Ac2k7JAAtcyi
ykRNCWttC5PqBJORUjOSRjO7tForkjHomFgEub+qnfDgSeR14N5u56efBFPOsRzf
IjAMO6lkYcGHa9hFSpzCNp319gH4yIXL+jXUs+3oyOruHVWHtRVTriGZ7eFgs6lU
gSt6+1V59gKjQtYHWWVEsE3f9YIB2zmFaQWHsK1qK3CAf5lNhsfDMXFNrNWSu+SB
MPWcNdxY7tdbfjPC4srJSs/YIfhEhuqLK6cR6Z8gwQKBgQD4dNluCVPIllWiPi95
peztrYDVmVYVDU0XKZ01EDqydDWJyUWYuMG77g/vPokrYHRB+rCYTDbpsO3d7qB9
tJoTOhJ1juPqmgbUwZEKokb64KKg+JMGH0elAD0mlIcxrkkvppapA/WGTXV84Nf8
4tTCWKoyUiyi8jZfby8rIpzAiQKBgQDFNvZraXsTcdikQQcAGclK6zdAVf0J1OE6
b1zZFQhlao38hWz/NdbvwHvtqhNgx7r9eO3Jg250atFHm8YD+OTQPz2xBecbTBeY
/F3tiD6NiL2TClBlaB7aR9KchaFypOmtR02UFPh4o0cX03s8D8qmr30MOBkjqgxm
spNU35qPiQKBgQCdVnHyqtlx5zHngnXSFW9KvFsf6PCIeFnfVy0E03g4VjspPFpk
cmvNNN7GZNW8sGIu/jAi4fDMYIzhxCHCOUJw9o+F/qz6ffvhc4sELuvAJ80VHxUM
BXb7WIFhEyHiJjqWgGpcMfOjzx2drU1aCdMuF7QAFeXKcpRYLzKxoEOf8QKBgQCx
w14Q6a4vk8HkJF0sARJI/oX57sg70XAG3RSC9AtyZr5/LMFXtW79ArJyQohfBwmM
qjEkH90zAImNk2LEd9e/whFYfGqZV1g55NjBX7qKlwPSA0z+awDMXksAHQ+up+md
8BSEcvaYvww49L4zIETZRHthxTsbw46UD0jwCvFliQKBgHfJRPg9u2OCZF+jOtK2
swI2r+4/q7Ki7mBuHlnceRDfgb+1lvv2QmM0M/p6ijf7/SequksdJSr2jLmCp/K3
HwSFaGgoHSt/nkcCCi7LR9fhM2MeLrEIV4E937Ii2wkt5/JXGwwYPbadELPb84On
q0oUrqcHheFb4aCv1N5io6ok
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
}

In Rust code, i return the 'ClientKey' struct in the function which implements Reply as Json as below
Struct
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Default, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct ClientKey {
    pub token_uri: String,
    pub kid: String,
    pub private_key: String,
}

Function return
 Ok(ClientKey {
       kid, // random id generated using rand crate
       private_key: format!("{}", pvt_key), // Generated from openssl and returned from a function in actual code
       token_uri: format!("{}", "http://example.com/token")
   })

Warp Reply impl
impl Reply for ClientKey {
    fn into_response(self) -> Response {
        warp::reply::json(&self).into_response()
    }
}


Your desired output would be invalid JSON, control characters like newlines are to be escaped like \n.

This is invalid JSON:
{
    "token_uri": "http://example.com/token",
    "kid": "keyid",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
}

I've added the missing " character on the last line of the private key.  that's not sufficient to make the data valid JSON.
As stated in the comments, control characters cannot appear in a JSON string value and must be escaped.  Per RFC 8259: The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format, Section 7: Strings (bolding mine):

The representation of strings is similar to conventions used in the C
family of programming languages.  A string begins and ends with
quotation marks.  All Unicode characters may be placed within the
quotation marks, except for the characters that MUST be escaped:
quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000
through U+001F).
Any character may be escaped.  If the character is in the Basic
Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF), then it may be
represented as a six-character sequence: a reverse solidus, followed
by the lowercase letter u, followed by four hexadecimal digits that
encode the character's code point.  The hexadecimal letters A through
F can be uppercase or lowercase.  So, for example, a string
containing only a single reverse solidus character may be represented
as "\u005C".
Alternatively, there are two-character sequence escape
representations of some popular characters.  So, for example, a
string containing only a single reverse solidus character may be
represented more compactly as "\\".
To escape an extended character that is not in the Basic Multilingual
Plane, the character is represented as a 12-character sequence,
encoding the UTF-16 surrogate pair.  So, for example, a string
containing only the G clef character (U+1D11E) may be represented as
"\uD834\uDD1E".
 string = quotation-mark *char quotation-mark

 char = unescaped /
     escape (
         %x22 /          ; "    quotation mark  U+0022
         %x5C /          ; \    reverse solidus U+005C
         %x2F /          ; /    solidus         U+002F
         %x62 /          ; b    backspace       U+0008
         %x66 /          ; f    form feed       U+000C
         %x6E /          ; n    line feed       U+000A
         %x72 /          ; r    carriage return U+000D
         %x74 /          ; t    tab             U+0009
         %x75 4HEXDIG )  ; uXXXX                U+XXXX


Note that "line feed" is U+000A - one of the control characters that must be escaped.

OT:  I do hope that's not your real private key.  It's no longer private if it is a real one.

Obvious that is dummy private key, not the real one @andrew-henle. I already know from the RFC especially for such keys to be with control characters. But this is accessed manually by internal users within our team (Not deployed as a app or system). So its suggested to format and provide internally in order to make life easier.

@Armani_bologne Then do not use JSON. Just return a String that you formatted yourself how you like.

@Armani_bologne So its suggested to format and provide internally in order to make life easier  Until someone tries to treat your fake JSON as actual JSON and blames you for producing invalid JSON.
